# PHP: Not connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database called message, with a table called user in it.
The table, 'user' has five columns, user_id which is the primary key and auto increments.
Then is the first name last name username and password.
But when i press the submit button, it shows me error connecting.
Cannot find the error!

What could it be?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<title> Create Account
</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php

$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'message') or die("Error");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    if($_POST['password']==$_POST['repassword'])
    {
        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $password_hash=sha1($password);
        $query="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, password)"."VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$password_hash')";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Error Connecting");
        echo "Account Created!";
        mysqli_close($dbc);


    }
    else
    {
        echo "Passwords do not match";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you selected table `user` via `mysqli_select_db`? I couldn't see it ya!

Comment: Not directly related to the problem, but this is **very** misleading for users reporting bugs and you debugging/asking for help as well: If `mysqli_query()` fails you should report it as "Query failed" or "Couldn't create account". It should never state "Error Connecting", because at that point in time you're either connected already or it failed above ("Errror").

Comment: Make sure your database server is running (and if it is using default port), try using mysqli_connect_error() to see if there is something more informative. Src:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: try print_r($result); die(); to see what returns

Comment: put the insert query inside try catch statment to see whats the real php exception ... i think that will give u the specific problem

Comment: @LeoBali procedural mysqli won't throw exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `""` around the fields you are about to insert.

You presently have:

```
$query="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, password)"."VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$username', '$password_hash')";
```

Do this instead:

```
$query='INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, password) '.
   'VALUES("'.$fname.'", "'.$lname.'", "'.$username.'", "'.$password_hash.'")';
```

Comment: They are interpolated in nested quotes

Comment: Better yet, use backticks and there is no need for "."VALUES remove the "." and backtick".$fname."+backtick, and for debug, echo $query, copy paste the query in your phpMyAdmin and see what error it gives you.

Comment: It worked thanks! 
I just need to clear my firm after the account is created! 
How can I do that?

Comment: gr8! Your firm ..? Dont quite follow.

Comment: Clear the form** Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

change your insert query to

```
$query="INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, username, password) VALUES('".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$username."', '".$password_hash."')";
```

Comment: Thanks it worked!
I would like to know why do we have to write in this format? Cause I guess the earlier one was correct as well.